# Documentation of Telegram methods for bots?

Tags: python-requests, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a message and then edit it using a bot in Telegram. I am doing so with Python module `requests`. I cannot find the documentation for the methods. I found [this](https://core.telegram.org/methods), however the documentation for [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage) and for [`editMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage) seems to be wrong. Below I will illustrate what I mean.

Following tutorials (for example [this one](https://www.atareao.es/tutorial/crea-tu-propio-bot-para-telegram/bot-en-python-para-telegram/)) I have succeeded in sending, but not yet editing. This is my MWE:

```
import requests

BOT_TOKEN = ':)'
CHAT_ID = ':)'

def send_message(message):
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage',
        data = {
            'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
            'text': message,
        }
    )
    return response.json()

def edit_message(message, msg_id):
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/editMessage',
        data = {
            'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
            'text': message,
            'id': str(msg_id),
        }
    )
    return response.json()

print('Sending...')
response = send_message('New message')
print(response)
print('Editing...')
print(edit_message('This message has been edited.', response['result']['message_id']))
```

After executing this code, this is the output:

```
Sending...
{'ok': True, 'result': {'message_id': 334, 'from': {'id': ---, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': '---', 'username': '---'}, 'chat': {'id': ---, 'first_name': '---', 'last_name': '---', 'username': '---', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1613550367, 'text': 'New message'}}
Editing...
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 404, 'description': 'Not Found'}
```

and the message is effectively sent by the bot, but not edited.

According to the documentation of [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage) this should be

```
def send_message(message):
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage',
        data = {
            'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
            'message': message,
        }
    )
    return response.json()
```

where `text` was changed by `message`. This, however, does not work. So either the documentation is wrong or I am looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking the Telegram core API, you should check the [Telegram Rest API Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext).

There you'll find the [`editmessagetext`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) method;

> **editMessageText**
>
> Use this method **to edit text** and game messages. On success, if the edited message is not an inline message, the edited Message is returned, otherwise True is returned.

I've edited your script, so that the `edit_message` function uses the above method;

```py
import requests

BOT_TOKEN = '~~'
CHAT_ID = '~~'

def send_message(message):
    response = requests.request('GET', f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage?', data={
        'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
        'text': message
    })
    return response.json()

def edit_message(message, msg_id):
    response = requests.request('GET', f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/editMessageText?', data={
        'chat_id': CHAT_ID,
        'text': message,
        'message_id': str(msg_id)
    })
    return response.json()


print('Sending first message')
response = send_message('StackOverflow Question')

print('Sending...')
response = send_message('Newmessage')

print('Editing...')
print(edit_message('This message has been edited.', response['result']['message_id']))
```

[image]

```
Sending first message
Sending...
Editing...
{'ok': True, 'result': {'message_id': 219, 'from': {'id': ?, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': '?', 'username': '?'}, 'chat': {'id': ?, 'first_name': '?', 'username': '?', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1613568086, 'edit_date': 1613568086, 'text': 'This message has been edited.'}}
```